# how to research arabic words in text using PHP？

Tags: php, arabic, arabic-support

I have a arabic keyword. how to compare it with a text to find that with PHP ， How many times has the keyword appeared ？
Arabic words are difficult to deal with PHP.

Can i use Regular Expressions to solve it？

If you can, trouble tell me a detailed solution

Comment: Are you using UTF8? Are you using a database? Show us your usage so we know what exactly you're trying to do and what is happening.

Comment: please show what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

I just tested preg_match_all and it appears to work.

```
$arabic_word = 'الكلمة';
$arabic_text = 'آمل أن يكون هذا يعمل هذه هي بعض بعبارة أخرى الكلمة هذه هي بعض الكلمة بعبارة أخرى آمل أن الكلمة يكون هذا يعمل';

if(preg_match_all("/$arabic_word/", $arabic_text, $matches)) {
    echo count($matches[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I restrict only Arabic letters or English letters or numbers or underscore inside my input validation code

```
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ أ-ي]/u",$_GET['input'])){echo"error";}
//    /u is for UNICODE, Arabic letters didn't work with me without it
```

---

If you are using UNICODE everywhere, then there is nothing called (Arabic,Thai, English,...) all of them are just characters that are supported in UNICODE.

So using any PHP string search function will do the trick